# Magnolia CMS React Integration

Tags: reactjs, magnolia

I am trying to integrate a React SPA I have with Magnolia using the external SPA  method and I'm failing painfully. I have downloaded the tomcat bundle with the demo webapp of Magnolia (version 6.2.23). I tried to follow the instructions as described [here](https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/headless/spa-development/SPA-hosting.html) and modified the `prototype.yaml` as described and replaced its contents with the following:

```
$type: spa
title: 'React: Basic'
baseUrl: http://localhost:3000
routeTemplate: '{{@path}}'
dialog: spa-lm:pages/basic
class: info.magnolia.rendering.spa.renderer.SpaRenderableDefinition
```

However, when I try to visit the public part of the application I get redirected to the `travel.html` of the demo app and get the following error in my logs.

```
2022-09-14 11:01:32,229 ERROR ndering.engine.ModeDependentRenderExceptionHandler: Error while rendering [/travel] with template [travel-demo:pages/home] for URI [/travel.html]:
RenderException: No template script defined for the template definition [info.magnolia.module.site.templates.PageTemplateDefinition@16789e26[id=<null>,name=home,renderType=site,description=<null>,title=<null>,templateScript=<null>,autoGeneration=info.magnolia.rendering.template.configured.ConfiguredAutoGeneration@3606bfbe[content={},generatorClass=<null>]]]
info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderException: No template script defined for the template definition [info.magnolia.module.site.templates.PageTemplateDefinition@16789e26[id=<null>,name=home,renderType=site,description=<null>,title=<null>,templateScript=<null>,autoGeneration=info.magnolia.rendering.template.configured.ConfiguredAutoGeneration@3606bfbe[content={},generatorClass=<null>]]]
        at info.magnolia.rendering.renderer.AbstractRenderer.render(AbstractRenderer.java:150) ~[magnolia-rendering-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.site.renderer.SiteAwareRendererWrapper.render(SiteAwareRendererWrapper.java:108) ~[magnolia-site-1.4.4.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine.render(DefaultRenderingEngine.java:120) ~[magnolia-rendering-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.DefaultRenderingEngine$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$73fe14cc.render(<generated>) ~[magnolia-rendering-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter.render(RenderingFilter.java:195) ~[magnolia-rendering-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter.handleTemplateRequest(RenderingFilter.java:140) ~[magnolia-rendering-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.rendering.engine.RenderingFilter.doFilter(RenderingFilter.java:94) ~[magnolia-rendering-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.rendering.model.ModelExecutionFilter.doFilter(ModelExecutionFilter.java:109) ~[magnolia-rendering-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AggregatorFilter.doFilter(AggregatorFilter.java:133) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RepositoryMappingFilter.doFilter(RepositoryMappingFilter.java:121) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:75) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:74) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:75) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.Store.processCacheRequest(Store.java:88) ~[magnolia-cache-core-5.9.4.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.executor.CompositeExecutor.processCacheRequest(CompositeExecutor.java:66) ~[magnolia-cache-core-5.9.4.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:164) ~[magnolia-cache-core-5.9.4.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.i18n.I18nContentSupportFilter.doFilter(I18nContentSupportFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.virtualuri.VirtualUriFilter.doFilter(VirtualUriFilter.java:102) ~[magnolia-virtual-uri-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.RangeSupportFilter.doFilter(RangeSupportFilter.java:78) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.BaseSecurityFilter.doFilter(BaseSecurityFilter.java:57) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cors.AbstractCorsFilter.doFilter(AbstractCorsFilter.java:77) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.SecurityCallbackFilter.doFilter(SecurityCallbackFilter.java:84) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:94) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.site.filters.SiteMergeFilter.doFilter(SiteMergeFilter.java:119) ~[magnolia-site-1.4.4.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultiChannelFilter.doFilter(MultiChannelFilter.java:83) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.module.cache.filter.GZipFilter.doFilter(GZipFilter.java:74) ~[magnolia-cache-core-5.9.4.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.auth.login.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:128) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:74) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.security.CsrfTokenFilterBase.doFilter(CsrfTokenFilterBase.java:99) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:75) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:81) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MultipartRequestFilter.doFilter(MultipartRequestFilter.java:151) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestAbstractMgnlFilter.java:59) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeFilter.java:155) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:128) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterChain.doFilter(MgnlFilterChain.java:79) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:75) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.AbstractMgnlFilter.doFilter(AbstractMgnlFilter.java:85) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.doFilter(SafeDestroyMgnlFilterWrapper.java:107) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlFilterDispatcher.doDispatch(MgnlFilterDispatcher.java:67) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:110) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at info.magnolia.cms.filters.MgnlMainFilter.doFilter(MgnlMainFilter.java:96) ~[magnolia-core-6.2.23.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
2022-09-14 11:01:32,242 WARN  info.magnolia.cms.filters.ContentTypeFilter       : Content type for http://localhost:8080/magnoliaPublic/travel.html is not set.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Magnolia's documentation seems very sparse in this area to me.

Answer (score 1):

In external SPA settings, the site prototype needs to be of `$type: spaPrototype`. Also, the actual page templates need to be `$type: siteSpa`.

Note that the `$type` notation is a replacement for the `class` property, so you can remove those from the definition.

Hope that helps.